# Find Repeat and Missing Array TLE in InterviewBit

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, vector

You are given a read only array of n integers from 1 to n.

Each integer appears exactly once except A which appears twice and B which is missing.

Return A and B.

Here is the solution  tried :

```
vector<int> Solution::repeatedNumber(const vector<int> &A) {
  int n=A.size();
   vector<int> res(2);
  unordered_map<int, int> m;
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
      m[A[i]]++;
      if(m[A[i]]==2)
         res[0]=A[i];
  }
    
  for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
      if(m.find(i)==m.end()){
        res[1]=i;
        break;
       }
  }
   return res;
}
```

However I am getting TLE for a test case (which is too big, cannot paste it here)

The solution in the editorial is as follows :

```
vector<int> Solution::repeatedNumber(const vector<int> &A) {
    int n=A.size();
    vector<bool> v(n+1,false);
    v[0]=true;
    vector<int> ans;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(v[A[i]]==true){
            ans.push_back(A[i]);
        }
        v[A[i]]=true;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n+1;i++){
        if(v[i]==false){
            ans.push_back(i);
            break;
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```

This solution is almost the same as mine. The only difference is usage of map instead of a vector of bool.
Why am I getting a TLE for approach 1 ?

Comment: FYI, usually a TLE error means that you need a faster or more efficient algorithm.  Micro optimizations won't help, you'll need to save more time.

Comment: You should take a large set of input data and use it to profile both algorithms.  Hopefully, the profiling can show you where most of the time is spent (although some profilers are limited to the function level, not inside functions).

Comment: You've discovered big-O's dirty little secret. In theory, both solutions have the same time complexity (I'm assuming that `unordered_map` is implemented with a hash table). So in theory, both solutions have the same performance. But in practice, your solution has a much higher constant factor, so it's substantially slower. You should time both solutions to see how much slower.

Comment: @OP In reality, a direct array access is faster than a map lookup, which your solution is doing.

Answer (score 4):

There's also a numeric approach that doesn't involve extra storage or the final search through the map/array for the missing element.

If we sum the values in the supplied array and compare it to the sum to `n`, i.e. `(n(n+1)/2)` we get the quantity `a-b`.

If we also sum the squares of the values and compare to the sum to `n^2`, i.e. `n(n+1)(2n+1)/6`, we get the quantity `a^2 - b^2`. This of course is equal to `(a-b)(a+b)`. From these with some basic algebra we can determine the values of `a` and `b`.

As an example, suppose we are given `n=4`, and the array `{4, 2, 3, 4}`, where `a = 4` and `b = 1`.

```
a - b = 13 - 10 = 3 (eq 1)

a^2 - b^2 = 45 - 30 = 15

(a - b)(a + b) = 15 

Sub in (1)

3(a + b) = 15 

(a + b) = 5 (eq 2)

Adding (1) and (2)

2a = 8

a = 4

b = 1
```

And some Java code:

```
void repeatedNumber(int[] arr)
{
    int n = arr.length;
    
    int nsum = 0;
    int nnsum = 0;
    for(int v : arr)
    {
        nsum += v;
        nnsum += v*v;
    }
    
    int ndiff = nsum - n*(n+1)/2;
    int nndiff = nnsum - n*(n+1)*(2*n+1)/6;
    
    int a = (ndiff + nndiff/ndiff)/2;
    int b = a - ndiff;
    
    System.out.printf("a = %d, b = %d%n", a, b);
}
```

Test:

```
repeatedNumber(new int[] {4, 2, 3, 4});
```

Output:

```
a = 4, b = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

**The safest method is XOR method.

If we take XOR of all array elements with every element in range [1, n], even appearing elements will cancel each other. We are left with XOR of x and y, x ^ y, where x and y is the duplicate and missing element. Note that the duplicate element will be XORed three times in total, and the missing element will be XORed 1 time, whereas all other elements will be XORed twice.**

Comment: Can you elaborate how duplicate element will be XORed thrice. Do you mean we XOR it again? or what